# Using Regular Expression to match fields with an arbitrary delimiter

Tags: c#, regex

I suppose this should be an old question, however, I didn't find suitable solution in the forums after several hours searching.

I'm using C# and I know the `Regex.Split` and `String.Split` methods can be used to achieve the expected results. For some reason, I need to use a regular expression to match the required fields by specifying an arbitrary delimiter. For example, here is the string:

```
#DIV#This#DIV#is#DIV#"A  "#DIV#string#DIV#
```

Here, `#DIV#` is the delimiter and is going to be split as:

```
This
is
"A  "
string
```

How can I use a regular expression to match these values?

By the way, the leading and trailing `#DIV#` could also be ignored, for example, below source string should also be same result with above:

```
#DIV#This#DIV#is#DIV#"A  "#DIV#string

This#DIV#is#DIV#"A  "#DIV#string#DIV#

This#DIV#is#DIV#"A  "#DIV#string
```

Comment: ...did you try the obvious `"yourstring".Split("#DIV#")`? If so, why doesn't that work for you?

Comment: It's because of my generic design on the application. All the parsing comes from an external xml file and we apply the regular expression engine to fetch required fields.

Comment: Why don't you just apply `Regex.Split`, then pull out the pieces?

Comment: I will if there is not good solution found, but this will need to make a little modification of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

I think I found a way (mind it is not efficient!) to get rid of empty values with a regex.

```
var splits = Regex.Matches(strIn, @"(?<=#DIV#|^)(?:(?!#DIV#).)+?(?=$|#DIV#)");
```

See [demo on regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%23DIV%23%7C%5E)(%3F%3A(%3F!%23DIV%23).)%2B%3F(%3F%3D%5Cr%3F%24%7C%23DIV%23)&i=%23DIV%23This%23DIV%23is%23DIV%23%22A%20%23%20%22%23DIV%23string%23DIV%23%0D%0AThis%23DIV%23is%23DIV%23%22A%20%23%20%22%23DIV%23string%23DIV%23%0D%0A%23DIV%23%23DIV%23This%23DIV%23is%23DIV%23%22A%20%23%20%22%23DIV%23string%0D%0A%23DIV%23This%23DIV%23is%23DIV%23%22A%20%23%20%22%23DIV%23string&o=m) (mind the `\r?` is only to demo in Multiline mode, you do not need it when using in real life)

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Here is another approach using a regular `Split`:

```
var strIn = "#DIV#This#DIV#is#DIV#\"A # \"#DIV#string#DIV#";
var splitText = strIn.Split(new[] {"#DIV#"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Or else, you can use a regex to match the fields you need and then remove empty items with LINQ:

```
var spltsTxt2 = Regex.Matches(strIn, @"(?<=#DIV#|^).*?(?=#DIV#|$)").Cast<Match>().Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Value)).Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
```

Output:

[image] [image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This simplified expression is very closing to what I need except the null matching in the beginning and end. I know it's very simple to apply LINQ to filter these null matching. But this need to add some codes into the generic purpose application. Is it possible to filter the null matching just by regular expression instead of LINQ?

Comment: Well, I thought it was impossible, but please try `Regex.Matches(strIn, @"(?<=#DIV#|^)(?:(?!#DIV#).)+?(?=$|#DIV#)");`. If it works for all cases you have please let me know, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match:

```
/#?DIV#?/g
```

And replace with `' '` (space)

But this will give trailing and leading spaces sometimes.. which can be removed by using [String.Trim()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx)

**Edit1:** If you want to match the field values you can use the following:

```
(?<=(#?DIV#?)|^)[^#]*?(?=(#?DIV#?)|$)
```

See [DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D(%23%3FDIV%23%3F)%7C%5E)%5B%5E%23%5D*%3F(%3F%3D(%23%3FDIV%23%3F)%7C%24)&i=DIV%23This%23DIV%23is%23DIV%23%22A%20%22%23DIV%23string%0D%0A%0D%0AThis%23DIV%23is%23DIV%23%22A%20%22%23DIV%23string%23DIV%23%0D%0A%0D%0AThis%23DIV%23is%23DIV%23%22A%20%22%23DIV%23string)

Edit2: More generalized regex for matching `#` in fields:

```
(?m)(?<=(^(?!#?DIV#)|(#?DIV#)))(.*?)(?=($|(#DIV#?)))
```

Comment: No, It only matches the delimiters instead of the field values.

Comment: It's closing, but it match the fields as: #This, #is, #"A  ", #string.
This pattern doesn't match the source string without delimiter at beginning and end either.

Comment: Excellent! I can now get all fields. However, I also got 2 extra NULL matching at the beginning and end, any way to remove them except by just tuning the expression?

Comment: I just found the expression will lost the fields if it contains '#' character, for example, if the source string is:

This#DIV#is#DIV#"A # "#DIV#string

where "A # " should be fetched but not got for above expression, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
#DIV#|(.+?)(?=#DIV#|$)
```

Try this.Grab the captures or groups.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fJ6cR4/21

Comment: Thanks! I'm using .Net regex and it matches either the fields and the delimiter "#DIV#". Any way to remove the matched delimiter?

Comment: @jones use `match.groups()`

Comment: For .net regular expression, there are 9 matches and 2 groups for each match (one for the matched pattern, the other is empty string). Any idea?